# Facebook Javascript SDK, how to know when async script has been loaded?

Tags: javascript, facebook, asynchronous, facebook-javascript-sdk

I do include facebook snippet like so

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
          appId      : 'someAppId',
          cookie     : true,
          xfbml      : true,
          version    : 'v2.8'
      });
  };

  (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Then, somewhere in my code, i will be doing something like

```
FB.foo.bar();
```

How i know when the script has done loading and therefore the `FB` object does exists?

Answer (score 0):

That is what `window.fbAsyncInit` is for, the JavaScript SDK is loaded when you hit that callback function. You can use FB right after `FB.init`.